# Pdf Not Generated using wkhtmltopdf using automated linux Bash Shell Script?

Tags: linux

I am trying to generate pdf using automated bash shell script, that script after every min checks the content of a file url.txt which conatins all urls line by line and i am using wkhtmltopdf for pdf generation

But the problem is pdf is not generated in the automated process but if i manually invoke that script pdf is generated. If anyone knows the solution please provide it to me?
Code of script is:

while read line;
do 
 wkhtmltopdf $line /var/www/images/Upload_files/name_of_file.pdf
done < /var/www/url/url.txt

Comment: Sometimes when you run jobs out of cron you don't have the same environment as you would when running from shell - especially paths to bin files like wkhtmltopdf. Have you tried callling it with the full path?

Comment: i have used the complete path i.e /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf but still it is not working

Comment: A bit of debugging might help you - after `do`, add something like `echo "processing $line"`. It is a good idea to always log automations to a file, so on your crontab line, add `>> /tmp/log.txt 2>&1` after the command to log all of the script's output. This should help finding the problem

Comment: Thanks for help the shell script is working fine with the wkhtmltopdf file that i have downloaded from code.google.com but it is not working with wkhtmltopdf that i have downloaded with synaptic manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run it in cron then the most likely reason that it wouldn't work is because lack of an X server. In that case one solution is to use [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)

Try running your `wkhtmltopdf` using `xvfb-run` like this in a no-X environment, say, by ssh-ing to localhost and verify that the `$DISPLAY` environment variable is not set:

```
$ xvfb-run -e /tmp/xvfb-error.log -s'-screen 0 1024x768x24' wkhtmltopdf somefile.html output.pdf
```

If that works fine then put in in a cron job that runs every 1 minute to test whether that one liner works under cron.

Otherwise check the `/tmp/xvfb-error.log` file to see if `xvfb` gives any error.

*It would be helpful if you can state the error message that you got when it doesn't work*

Comment: Heed @mogoman's advice - check your cron job logs for errors. Normally the output of commands run by cron job is emailed somewhere. So either check that email or redirect the stderr and stdout of the command to another file and inspect the content.

Comment: on manually invocation of above command it works fine and pdf is generated but when i put it in cron job pdf is not generated and xvfb-error.log has message Server is already active for Display 99 If the server is no longer running, remove /tmp/X.99-lock and start again

Comment: i have gone through Mogoman's advice that file says xvfb-run:error : Xvfb Failed to start

Comment: Try changing the screen argument to xvfb-run from `-screen 0 1024x768x24` to `-screen 1 1024x768x24`

Comment: Thanks holygeek for the help,shell script is working fine with the wkhtmltopdf file that i have downloaded from code.google.com but it is not working with wkhtmltopdf that i have downloaded with synaptic manager